# Create and show a PDF file from a Lotus Notes action

Tags: pdf-generation, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm using an action inside a form to create a Word document, using the CreateObject("Word.application") method, then I modify it to my liking and save it in a temp directory.

I can show the Word document as soon as it is created by calling nameOfTheDocument.visible(true), and by modifying the Save action I can save the newly created document as a PDF, however I can't find a way to show it to the user.

Trying to call visible(true) on the PDF object results in error "Instance member VISIBLE does not exist"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588209/lotus-notes-lotusscript-shell-function-illegal-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used the Shell command to launch PDFs in the past.  Something like the below.  The only downside to this is if the location of the executable changes (whether from upgrade or change to a different program) the code breaks.

```
Dim ProgPath$, FilePath$
Dim result As Integer
'Path of the executable
ProgPath$ = |"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 7.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"|
'Path of the file to open
FilePath$ = | "C:\TestFile.PDF"|
result = Shell(ProgPath$ & FilePath$,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... The best and right way - use OS file association.
I'm use java way:

```
//Win
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filePath);
p.waitFor();
//MacOS.*Nix
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open " + filePath);
p.waitFor();
```

But you can call this command on Lotusscript:

```
Shell({rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler } & fullFilePath,1)
'or
Shell({/usr/bin/open } & fullFilePath,1)
```